# Convert int string to hex string

Tags: c#

How would I convert a string that represents an integer like "4322566" to a hex string?

Comment: You want to take a string equal to "4322566" and generate "41F506", right?

Comment: Yeah that is what I want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`string s = int.Parse("4322566").ToString("X");`

Comment: You may want to make this more fault-tollerant with `TryParse`

Comment: I get a overflow exception when attempting to convert 2309737967

Comment: 2309737967 is above int.MaxValue (2147483647). Use long instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
int temp = 0;
string hexOut = string.Empty;
if(int.TryParse(yourIntString, out temp))
{
    hexOut = temp.ToString("X");
}
```

To handle larger numbers per your comment, written as a method

```
public static string ConvertToHexString(string intText)
{
    long temp = 0; 
    string hexOut = string.Empty; 
    if(long.TryParse(intText, out temp))
    { 
        hexOut = temp.ToString("X"); 
    } 
    return hexOut;
}
```

Comment: I get a overflow exception when attempting to convert 2309737967

Comment: change the type of temp to `long` and use `long.TryParse`

Answer (score 1):

Try `.ToString("X")`.

Answer (score 1):

or .ToString("x") if you prefer lowercase hex.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int otherVar= int.Parse(hexstring ,
System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: int -> string, not string -> int.